# Changing the output layer of a pre-trained model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a pre-trained model and want to change only the output layer to a new one with more units. In this case the old output layer had 18 units and the new one should have 20.

My current implementation of this looks like this:

```
old_model = load_model(model_filepath)
helper_model = Model(inputs=old_model.inputs, outputs=old_model.layers[-2].output)
new_output = Dense(units = old_model.layers[-1].units + increment, activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=l1_l2(l1l2[0],
                       l1l2[1]))(helper_model.output)
new_model = Model(inputs=helper_model.input, outputs=new_output)
```

If I print new_model.summary() and look at the last layer, everything looks fine:

```
 dense (Dense)               (None, 20)                   2580      ['dropout[0][0]']

======================================================================================
```

However, when I try to train the new_model, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 18) and (None, 20) are incompatible
```

Why do I receive this and how do I fix this? Do I maybe need a reshape layer?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the number of units in the output layer from 18 to 20, you'll need to make adjustments depending on the framework or library you're using for your neural network implementation.

**Mismatch in Number of Units:**

The last layer of the helper_model has 18 units, but you are trying to create a new output layer with old_model.layers[-1].units + increment, which evaluates to 20 units.

In your code, you are incrementing the number of units by some variable increment:

> new_output = Dense(units=old_model.layers[-1].units + increment,
> activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=l1_l2(l1l2[0],
> l1l2[1]))(helper_model.output)

Ensure that the value of increment is correct and aligns with your intended output shape. If you want the output shape to be (None, 20), make sure that units is set to 20 in the Dense layer:

> new_output = Dense(units=20, activation='softmax',
> activity_regularizer=l1_l2(l1l2[0], l1l2[1]))(helper_model.output)

If you still encounter issues, here are a few things to check:

**Data Shapes:** Ensure that your input data has the correct shape for your model. The input shape of the model should match the shape of your input data.

**Compile Step:** When compiling the model, make sure that the loss function and metrics are compatible with your problem and that you are using the correct optimizer.